# The database returned no natively generated identity value

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, db2, websphere

I am using IBM DB2 V 9.1.0.356. I am using DB2 JDBC driver version 9.7.

I am using these technologies for my application.

Spring MVC, Hibernate, DB2, Websphere

In my Create Table script; ID column is generated as:

```
ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
```

In Java Entity class its configured as:

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column( name = "id", nullable = false  )
```

When I saves and object by calling this through hibernate:

```
*.save(persistentObject);
```

Data is saved. But I got following Exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: The database returned no natively generated identity value
at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorFactory.getGeneratedIdentity(IdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:90)
```

**Note:** My application is configured on two servers on different machines. From one machine I can succefully save data; but from other I got above mentioned exception.

Comment: Do those to app server machines work with the same database or does each instance have its own DB?

Comment: You use JDBC Type 4 driver or any native DB2 driver?

Comment: I am using two jars for DB2 drivers. 1: db2jcc_license_cu.jar 2: db2jcc.jar. I don't know the correct version but I think its 9.7.

Comment: So you do not have DB2 Client installed? 'Type 4' means native Java, not just a bridge to 'machine code' database driver...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that this works on one WebSphere server and fails on another although they both connect to the same database suggests that there is an issue with the version of the JDBC driver. I would check that first.

Comment: Why did you downvote that answer? There is a known issue with certain versions of the DB2 JDBC driver that causes this exact error. If you indeed checked that you are using the same version on both servers, then you should have no problem to let us know which version you are using.

Comment: I am using two jars for DB2 drivers. 1: db2jcc_license_cu.jar 2: db2jcc.jar. I don't know the correct version but I think its 9.7. Using same jars for both servers that's why I downvoted so that other viewers can see that there may be some other problem.

Comment: I think you should review the page that describes the "vote down" privilege, in particular the part where it says "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."

Comment: @imran tariq: I'd rather not downvote an answer like this as your problem may be caused by certain fairly complex configuration issues. The answer just provides a hint and is not a 'low quality' answer...

Comment: Ok ok. Reverting my decision. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: WebSphere logs the version number of the JDBC driver when the first JNDI lookup of the data source occurs. Note that the version number doesn't use the same scheme as the DB2 version number. It looks like "3.61.84". Do you see these messages in the logs?

Comment: I am using IBM DB2 V 9.1.0.356. I am using DB2 JDBC driver version 9.7. Will this version difference matters?

Comment: Although the JDBC drivers are shipped with DB2, there is no 1-to-1 correspondence between drivers versions and DB2 versions. Therefore speaking about "JDBC driver version 9.7" is actually incorrect. These drivers are designed to connect to older DB2 versions and DB2 is designed to receive connections from older clients. E.g. we are using a single driver version to connect to DB2 9.5 LUW and DB2 8.1 on z/OS.

Answer (score 1):

The above Exception can also occur if the @id annotated property mapped column dose not support auto generation of id.

i.e.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

using

```
Use @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that while creating your table id field should be marked as auto-increment and then use

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Answer (score 0):

check primary key in database, if it is not auto increment then you will get this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAvrL.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).